# Nvidia-smi command not found - nvidia drivers installed

Tags: driver, nvidia

**~$ nvidia-smi
nvidia-smi: command not found
~$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_12_23:07:04_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.2, V9.2.148**

Its worked before. I made changes in grub using the command

gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

but revert it back. (I don't know if it could have effect)

Comment: How did you install cuda?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**
The most common reason for any “command not found” error is that the software being accessed is not installed on the system. Check out the example below where the tool is not installed on the system and the error “nvidia-smi command not found” is thrown:

**Solution**
The best way of resolving this error is to install the “nvidia-utils” package which will also contain the “nvidia-smi” tool inside it. To install this package, run the command in the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-utils-515
```

I got the detailed solution form this post: https://itslinuxfoss.com/fix-nvidia-smi-command-not-found-error/